# Is it possible to set global hotkey in WinRT?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

I want to create simple screenshot application for Win RT. I want to add feature to capture screenshot by hotkey (only for users with keyboard). How I can do that?

Comment: WinRT already has a global screenshot hotkey (which is Windows Key + volume button down). Once the screenshot is taken your app can receive it by declaring it supports [Share Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758316.aspx) contract for images. I understand, it is not exactly what you are asking, but it is the how content sharing works in Windows Store apps...

Comment: Even if you managed to register your hotkey (which you can't), how do you plan on scraping the screen of another app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it system-wide without jailbreaking, only application wide - with something like [CoreWindow.KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

My typical solution would be using *Win32 pInvoke* for `RegisterHotKey`, but that is not supported on *Windows RT*.

It would seem that a system-wide global hotkey is not possible on *RT*.